# execute script on load of current script

Tags: javascript, events

I want to do something like `document.currentScript.onload = function(){alert(0)};`. Basically, executing some code after the current script is done executing. How would you do that?

Note that this is an inline script. I want to set the onload handler only under certain conditions that can be known during the execution of current script only.

What I have tried:

1. The snippet above. This did not work and my guess is that you cannot set an onload handler on a currently executing script. My reasoning may be wrong though.
2. `document.write('\x3cscript>alert(0);\x3c/script>');`. My hope was that the content of `document.write` would execute after the current script has finished execution. However, it seems that the content is executing as soon as it is written on the page stream.

Comment: The question is not a duplicate. See my edit.

Comment: So why not override a callback (*which by default does nothing*) that is called at the end of your script.

Comment: Sure, that is an obvious solution. But I do not want to change the inline scripts. All the logic decision whether to do any code execution happens by overriding some DOM and Javascript native functions.

Comment: If there is some way to have some code execute after every `script` element is done executing (without modifying the `script`s themselves), that would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `load` event is fired [only for external scripts](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#script-processing-model:concept-script-external-3) (*your code would work if it was inside an external script*).

A Firefox **only** solution is to use the [`afterscriptexecute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/onafterscriptexecute) event.

```html
<script id="first">
  document.addEventListener("afterscriptexecute", function(e){
    console.log(`Script "${e.target.id}" just finished executing`);
  }, true);
</script>
<script id="second">console.log('a log');</script>
<script id="third">console.log('another log');</script>
<script id="fourth">console.log('yet another log');</script>
```

---

Other than these, i can only think (*as suggested in the comments*) to use an empty callback which is overridden with your code if your conditions are met.

Something like

```html
<script>
    let afterscriptexecute = function(){}; 
    
    // .. your code
    
    if (Math.random() < 0.5){ // if condition is met
       afterscriptexecute = function(){
         // do something
         alert('conditions were met');
       }
    }
    
    // end of your code
    
    afterscriptexecute();
</script>
```